# Safari cannot open the page because the address is invalid after successful uber oauth

Tags: ios, react-native, oauth, deep-linking, uber-api

I'm linking to the uber api authentication endpoints (`/authorize` and `/token`) via iOS and after a successful login, it returns "Safari cannot open the page because the address is invalid". I've narrowed this down to an iOS specific problem because the same react-native configuration works for Android.

I've tried a number of solutions.

Clear safari browsing history, web data, iPhone update, etc. Nothing has worked.

I believe URL Schemes under URL Types in info.plist has a pay here, but I'm struggling to wrap my head around what I need to put there.

Any thoughts?

Upon successful authentication, uber should return an access token for the user.

Comment: what return URL are you specifying?  Does your app respond to that URL?

Comment: @Paulw11 Are you referring to the redirect URL? Or is it the uber return URL that takes the user to the uber platform?

Comment: The redirect URL that the authenticating party (Uber in this case) uses to redirect back to your app in order to provide the token.  This would normally be something like `myGreatApp://` and `myGreatApp` needs to be registered as a URL type in your `info.plist` file

Comment: @Paulw11 I got through! Thanks man

Comment: @Paulw11 Legend, you saved me. This should be the accepted answer